# jquery post works only some of the time, but no error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery function like this:

```
function btnclick(btndatatxt) {
    $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
    btndata = document.getElementById(btndatatxt);
        if ($(btndata).hasClass('colorred')) {
            $(btndata).removeClass('colorred');
            $(btndata).addClass('colorgreen');
            checked = true;
        }
        else {
            $(btndata).removeClass('colorgreen');
            $(btndata).addClass('colorred');
            checked = false;
        }
        var link = 'UpdateCheckbox/?recordid=rpl1&completed=rpl2';
        link = link.replace("rpl1", btndatatxt);
        link = link.replace("rpl2", checked);
        link = link.replace("&amp;", "&");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: link,
        context: document.body,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    }).done(function () {
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    });
```

It is called when this button is clicked in my view:

`<button id="@btnID" class="@chkclass" value="@chkday" onclick="btnclick('@btnID')"></button>`

It works great until I publish it to my website.  Then it may or may not work.  As in, I load the page and click the button and it appears to change, but when I reload, the button is not changed.  This can happen multiple times.  Then I click the button again, and it appears to change, and that time I reload the page and it remains changed.

The code is not returning any errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

The controller code to save the changes in c# is:
...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCheckbox(string recordid, string completed)
        {
            string result = "error";
            try {
                int compl = 0;
                if (completed == "true")
                {
                    compl = 1;
                }               
                 result = EntriesModel.SaveCheck(recordid, compl);
                return Content(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = e.Message;
            }
            return Content(result);
        }
```

...

The controller code to get the model:

...
        public ActionResult OperatorBoard_Operate(int SelectedOperatorBoardID)
        {
            Entriesmodel.entries = new EntriesModel()
            entries = EntriesModel.GetEntries();
            return View("OperatorBoard", entries);
...

Routeconfig file:
...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SixS
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("ChartImg.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/ChartImg.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/{action}/ChartImg.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: What determines the initial class being either `colorgreen` or `colorred`?

Comment: Press F12 Developer tool to check console message.

Comment: The initial class is set by the @chkclass variable which is based on whether the value of a field is 1 or 0 in the model.  There are no console messages.

Comment: What makes you think the button css should persist after your page reload? The information you have given suggest that you are controlling the css with java script but then expect the css to persist after you refresh your page. If you are trying to do this kind of persistence, you will either require a persistence layer client side, or server side, but you haven't showed anything like it so it wouldn't work they way you expect it to.

Comment: If you click the button and your css changes, your code is working as expected, if you refresh your page and the css resets to original, then it is working as expected. If this is not your intended functionality, you will atleast need to provide more info of what @chkclass is and how that value is set.

Comment: @AbdulG I click the button and the css changes.  What it does not appear to do is post.  It works correctly when I debug in Visual Studio but not when I publish to IIS.  I will post the code.

Comment: @Remona include your RouteConfig file and your action `UpdateCheckbox`. It's important to note that the `.done` event will fire whether the ajax call was successful or not. Therefore, the issue is most likely sitting in your backend code

Comment: @AbdulG I have added it.

Comment: Ok I can see a few issues here. Before we begin, please format your action code for generating the model and receiving the ajax call. ie, include the `[HttpPost]` attribute if it exists

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code you requested.  Also, I realized today that the problem occurs in IE and not in Chrome.  So I debugged in IE and I can see the program stepping through the jquery code, but about 50% of the time, the css does not  change and the post does not happen.  I do not see any error messages so I do not know why.